# PHP: How to parse this xml with Simple XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to get the value of `url2` from the following xml:

```
<videoplayer>
    <embed_code>aaa</embed_code>
    <volume>bbb</volume>
    <stats_pixel>
        <secret>ccc</secret>
        <url>ddd</url>
        <url2>HOW TO GET THIS???</url2>
        <video_plays>
            <site_url>eee</site_url>
        </video_plays>
    </stats_pixel>
</videoplayer>
```

This didn't work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$xml->videoplayer[0]->stats_pixel->url2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`videoplayer` is root, so you shouldn't specify it, this should work:

```
echo $xml->stats_pixel->url2;;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to encode your URL:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode($url));
var_dump($xml);  //make sure you get a SimpleXMLElement here before using it...
```

Comment: I do get an object back. Funny thing is if I var_dump `$xml->videoplayer` I get `SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)` anything beyond that I get nothing back but the `trying to get property of non object` notice.

Comment: @JakeRow123 Can you add the output of var_dump($xml->videoplayer); to your question?